# iphone app - Custom B2B Apps

Tags: iphone, distribution

From this page (http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html) I've read this

> Custom B2B Apps
>
> You can also offer custom B2B apps directly to your business customers
>   who have a Volume Purchase Program account. A custom B2B app provides
>   a unique, tailored solution to address a specific business need or
>   requirement.

Does anyone have any more details about this?  i have an app idea that is specific for a individual company, say I am building an app for Company ABC, this app is solely for company ABC & no one else, how do I distribute such an an app (to Company ABC) & can I charge a monthly subscription for this app?

Thanks
kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you seen this:

http://www.apple.com/business/vpp/

"Custom B2B Apps for Business
In addition to offering volume purchasing of apps in the App Store, the Volume Purchase Program provides your business with an easy way to procure custom B2B apps built by third-party developers. Custom B2B apps are built to address a unique business need, and therefore are not available to the general public for purchase. "

Yes you can create an app for Company ABC only, and restrict only them as purchasers. I don't think you can make it a subscription though. Oh, and it's US businesses only.

Comment: Not rolled out outside US as far as I know. For now outside US we have to use enterprise program.

Comment: but how do you make distribution with enterprise program??
Imagine that you want to sell an app to a company, how do you distribute the app??

Comment: If the company has an an Enterprise account then either they can create the profiles or they can give you access and you can create the profiles. Then the profiles can be installed on the devices. Once a device has the profile the app will work and can be distributed to employees by email or any other mechanism. The profile and app could even be distributed together to users in a single zip.

Comment: When you mention profiles, you are talking about certificates, right!?
So I need the certificates of the company, and sign the code with it!? That's it? Thanks

Comment: Kind of, certificates are "used" to create the profiles and the profile is what goes on the device. See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ProvisioningDevelopment/ProvisioningDevelopment.html

Comment: Here's a link to the Enterprise Program documentation about wirelessly deploying apps: http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/#app43ad871e

Comment: Hi all , i want to clarify about custom b2b apps. Can we submit the App as Custom b2b App with the normal developer account? or is it necessary to have an Enterprise Developer account.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

B2B Apps need to go through Apples review just like normal apps do, but they will appear in some sort of a private store to which you may grant your client access. It is my understanding that, aside from that, normal rules apply.

That means you might be able to offer In App Purchases and lock most of the app down, unless the user purchases a subscription.

I do **not** know however if subscriptions can be purchased via the Volume Purchase Program.

As a rule of thumb, before entering "uncharted waters" by just developing your idea, you should just contact Apple about what you like to do. Ultimately it is their decision what they will approve, so I wouldn't rely on the opinion of *someone on the internet* before putting too much effort into it.

You should also be aware that the Volume Purchase Program is available in the United States only.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/
Look at bottom of page for other countries you can distribute to.